# Does returning an instance directly in a property create duplicate instances?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a class with a property that returns an array of strings.

```
public static string[] MyStrings
{
    get { return new string[] { "Foo", "Bar" }; }
}
```

Will this create multiple instances of `MyStrings` every time it is referenced? Are there compiler optimizations that effectively make it a singleton, or do I have to explicitly do something like this:

```
private static string[] _myStrings = new string[] { "Foo", "Bar" };
public static string[] MyStrings
{
    get { return _myStrings; }
}
```

Comment: using 'static' means only  1 object will ever be created and it would be created implicitly.

Comment: @NoChance For classes, yes, but not for properties. All `static` means on a property is that it is available statically on the type without needing an instance. https://dotnetfiddle.net/1Gs18K

Comment: Using 'new' with 'static', while valid is a bit confusing sometimes. My understanding was that a "static" = 1 copy.

Comment: Note that your optimization is extremely dangerous; anyone at all can change the contents of an array that they can read! That is, someone can say `MyStrings()[0] = "blah";` and now every other caller to `MyStrings()`, past and future, gets the change. This is why returning an array is often the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for the warning, you're right. Do you have a recommended alternative for cases like this?

Comment: @JacobStamm: The first thing to decide is the return type. Start by thinking about what operations the caller needs to perform on `MyStrings()`. If the main use case is `foreach` over the collection, then the return type should be the minimum possible: `IEnumerable<string>`.  Do they need access by index? If so, is an integer the best index, or is there a better key? Do they need to write to the collection *most of the time*? If they need to write to the collection 1% of the time, just make the caller call `ToList` or `ToArray`. And so on. **Design every method with the callers needs in mind**

Comment: Once you have the caller's needs in mind, consider whether the collection should be immutable. If yes, then return an immutable collection, or a read-only wrapper around a mutable collection.

Comment: Warning: The following note is intended to describe better syntax.  As Eric mentions, this is the wrong approach to solve your problem.  Newer versions of C# allow you to replace the second example with `public static string[] MyStrings { get;} = new string[] { "Foo", "Bar" };`.  Of course, you could also use a field ( `public static readonly string[] MyStrings = new string[] { "Foo", "Bar" };` ).

Answer (score 1):

> Will this create multiple instances of MyStrings every time it is referenced?

It will reuse the strings objects for the literals "Foo", and "Bar".

However, by definition of the `new` operator, the language is forced to create a new array object each time the getter is invoked, i.e. the `new` expression is run.

By definition, while string literals that match must be the same object:

```
"a" must == "a"
```

however,

```
new String ( "a" ) must != new String ( "a" )

new String [] { "a", "b" } must != new String [] { "a", "b" }
```

*where here I'm using == and != for reference equality, so by "must !=" I mean these must be different (string or string array) objects*.

That execution of two `new` expressions must each create a brand new object (i.e. cannot not return a shared object) goes to the definition of `new` in C# and Java — this holds for two executions of `new` even of identical arguments, and, even when constructing an instance of an immutable class, and, even when the two executions are the same expression (same line of code) run twice.

To eliminate the array creation you have to do something like you're suggesting later.

Another approach (though probably not practical here) is to use a factory method instead of `new` as they have more freedom, e.g. to return shared instances (or even return subclass), whereas `new` does not have this latitude.

---

While compiler optimization is not inconceivable, it would have issues.  For one, it would have to create the first/initial object, and store and relocate that for reuse later.  While this is done automatically for string literals, string literals have well understood behavior so, for example, they can be pre-created with impunity, and they don't require finalizers, further the definition of string literals suggests program lifetime anyway, so the runtime stores the string literals in global variables for later use — doing this in more general cases can be problematic.  Consider also that while string literals are immutable, string arrays are mutable, so analysis would have to take into account potential tests for object equality/inequality as well as potential mutations to the returned array (which would make it un-shareable).

More likely, the compiler optimization here that would help reduce the cost of these allocations is one that transforms heap allocation into stack allocation.

All in all, the alternative you suggest is likely to be the most effective; it is also perfectly readable IMHO.

Comment: What do you think of using a get-only automatic property that is auto-initialized instead of being backed by a field (assuming C# 6+, of course)? `private static string[] MyStrings { get; } = new string[] { "Foo", "Bar" };` Is the behavior the same, and do you consider it better or worse than the alternative in my original question?

Comment: I think that's even better.  Just one last thing, be aware that string array is mutable, so the consuming client (perhaps  you) could alter parts of your original and subsequent consumers would get that altered copy (same is true for the explicit backing field)...  (C# has read only collections, though, which might be more appropriate, depending on context).

Comment: @ErikEidt: `new String ( "a" ) != new String ( "a" )` does not compile.  I'm not sure what you intended to be there.

Comment: @Brian, what I said was that the object created by one `new` cannot be the same object as created another `new`.  I also never wrote `new String ( "a" ) != new String ( "a" )`, that would be misleading, especially in C# due to the operator overloading of != and == for string.  What I did say had several fragments of code that require more context to be run.

Comment: @Brian, if you want to put this to a test with the compiler and run it, put the following (in a method in a class): `if ( (object) new String ( "a" ) != (object) new String ( "a" ) ) Console.WriteLine ( "different objects" ); else Console.WriteLine ( "same object" );`.  Casting to object will test reference equality, and, putting it inside an statement will make it a legal statement.

Comment: @ErikEidt: The code in your comment also does not compile.  My point was that there is no String constructor which accepts a string.

Comment: @Brian, thanks for the info.  I am working in Visual Studio 15.9.5, where it compiles and executes; perhaps this new...

Comment: @ErikEidt: I was able to get this to compile in Visual Studio by switching from .Net Framework to .Net Core.  .Net Core compiles this by implicitly casting the `string` to a `ReadOnlySpan<char>`, which is available to one of the string constructors.

Comment: @Brain, ah, very good!  I hadn't thought of trying it those ways.